# grid point algorithm (finding the point in grid)

Tags: algorithm, euclidean-distance

I am searching for an algorithm such as the [closest pair of points algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

Instead of an arbitrary distance between all of the points, I have a grid system set up with the 4 points being the top-right, bottom-right, top-left, and bottom-left respectively. This keeps the distance between all the points constant.

say for example if I were to put an outside point on this grid, I need to find which grid square it would be in, assuming by finding the closest 4 points (giving me the end points of the grid square).

I was going to implement the algorithm for closest points, but since the points are all the same distance away from each other all the time I didn't know if this would merit a different more efficient algorithm.

I don't really need a detailed explanation of the answer, just a point in the right direction.

Comment: To clarify; you have a grid of squares, and you want to know which square an arbitrary point lies in?  (If it's not this, then it's probably worth adding a diagram to your post...)

Comment: no that is exactly what I need to do. I assumed that finding the 4 end points of the grid (top-right, bottom-right, top-left, and bottom-left) would be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is in 2 dimensions? Very simply, you could do this -- I used a similar technique to quickly optimize spatial clustering in a large scale data mining project.

Divide your coordinate space into a fixed number of grid lines in the X and Y directions (which it seems you have already done, by equally spacing these 4 points).

When you insert a point, divide its distance (integer division) from the origin in the X and Y direction by your grid step interval. Then you're left with two coordinates that identify the nearest X/Y grid intersection. Use the remainder to establish which side of the grid intersection your point belongs in.

If you want to get really complicated you could start using kD-Trees, etc... but I think this example is simple enough not to warrant any more complicated spatial partitioning.

Comment: Thank You for your advice, just some clarification, when you say 

**divide its distance from the origin in the X and Y direction by your grid step interval.**

do you mean divide its x and y components say by 5 (the size of each grid square) this would give me (x,y) * 5 is the nearest grid intersection?

Comment: Yes, say you have a point at (100,50). Your grid is setup to have the same width in X and Y (5 in this case), you would divide 100/5 = 20, 50/5 = 10. Your point would actually lie exactly on the boundary of the grid cell (20,10). And this would let you know that you could insert it into that cell; if there were a remainder in the X or Y direction, you would probably want to push it into the next-highest cell in that direction.

Comment: Thank You for your help. That seems much more straight forward that what I was thinking of.